# AdControl - sometimes no advertising and category is not right

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads

I add on my application 3 adcontrols.

1\I add 3 campaign and each campaign is associated to another category in the Microsoft Pub advertising configuration.
So I configure in the xaml the controls as below.

1. AdUnitId="150900"  AdUnitId="150902"  AdUnitId="150903"

I notice in my dev environment (not still deploy on the store), the content from the ad are the same, is-it the standard behavior? I think it shouldn't be the same because the id is differents, so my assumption is the result is the same whatever the environment.
Do you encountered the same behavior?

2\I notice sometimes only 1 of the 3 have an ad, sometimes the 3. Do you have some issues like that? No find a way to fix it, just relaunch the application...

[UPDATE]
1\ no find solution
2\ I use the event ErrorOccurred to define what I can do.
I use the refresh action. but it doesn't work, in that case the application turns in a while process until stop visual studio :). So I'm not convinced about this ad solution.
I configure too the ad to not collapsed when an issue is encountered, but in that case I expected to have the zone empty but with the design template applied. It's not the case, you have the entire zone empty.

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-test-mode-values(v=msads.20).aspx
"Live ads are not available in the emulator. You must use test values for the ApplicationId and AdUnitId when running in the emulator. To verify live ads, you will have to run the app on a device."

So for testing you should only use the test Ids from the mentioned site.
Also it's quite common that no ad is displayed in your banner - in case your app is running on phone in region where no Ad is right now available - no Ad is then displayed.

Comment: I agree with you. I use the device not the emulator and I use the right ID and I am in France. I notice the ad aren't localized regarding the displayed ad. " in case your app is running on phone in region where no Ad is right now available - no Ad is then displayed." => Sometimes, it's just a bug, I don't receive any ad.